# Atomic update speed and update if only exists

Tags: solr, atomic

***I am using Solr for suggestions, and i have two questions:***

1. Is Solr atomic updates fast enough to update suggestion popularity (popularity inc 1) on every query? Or the better way is to store all suggestions in Redis database and import them to Solr every 24 hours?
2. When I use [{suggestion:'my suggestion','popularity':{'inc': 1}}], and "my suggestion" suggestion doesn't exist in the index, Solr adds it to the index. But I need to update only existing suggestions. **How to increase popularity field only if suggestion exists?**

Answer (score 1):

1. I believe it will perform fine as long as you don't commit the changes on every update request but set up an autoCommit of 1 or 2 min in your solrconfig.xml

   - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#Update_Handler_Section
2. Solr 4.0 doesn’t partially update Lucene index, but instead removes a document from the index and indexes an updated one. Of course all of that is done on Solr side but b/c of this solr create a new document even if the old one does not exist. one way to get around this, is to make a required field in your schema and only populate that field if you are adding a new suggestion. in that case solr will not be able to create a new document for your incremental updates.